# how to get last email received or most recent inbox mail from Gmail API?

Tags: android, email, gmail, gmail-api

```
I have already login through GoogleApiClient in my application.  
I am also able to List of email matching query using google api sample.
```

[users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) 
    by this link ,I am getting the user email with query text(search word).

1.I need last email received using gmail api.

Answer (score 2):

[Listing](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) is only half the problem:

**Request**

```
maxResults = 1
q = -from:me

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?maxResults=1&q=-from%3Ame&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "1520a62ee385565e",
   "threadId": "1520a62ee385565e"
  }
 ],
 "nextPageToken": "17704551804303833190",
 "resultSizeEstimate": 1
}
```

After that, you need to [Get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) the specific email:

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/1520a62ee385565e?access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "id": "1520a62ee385565e",
 "threadId": "1520a62ee385565e",
 "labelIds": [
  "INBOX",
  "CATEGORY_SOCIAL",
  "UNREAD"
 ],
 "snippet": "Snippet of the message",
 "historyId": "701108",
 "internalDate": "1451873198000",
 "payload": {
  "mimeType": "multipart/alternative",
...
```